# Text transition animation effect issue in IE (I don't know why) HTML+ CSS3

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, animation, invisible

I have a text animation and it runs on most browser but I have problem with Internet Explorer.I can't find where is the problem,please help me.I think it's a problem with shadows on internet explorer, but I'm not sure.  I work with wordpress, if it is a factor,  and I put the html code in text editor and css in style.css:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#agentie-de-publicitate-full-service:target {
display:none;
}
  @media and screen (max-width: 600px) {
.sp-container h2 {
display:none;
font-size:2px !important;}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
font-size:2px !important;
}

}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Electrolize';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Electrolize'), local('Electrolize-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/electrolize/v2/DDy9sgU2U7S4xAwH5thnJ4bN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format('woff');
}


.container1{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow:visible;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1.main,p.demos {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
 animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 99999;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81));
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81));
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81));
 background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81));
}
.sp-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 line-height: 6vw !important;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 font-size: 5.3vw;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: transparent;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;

}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
 animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
 font-size: 100px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
 animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
 -webkit-animation: none;
 -moz-animation: none;
 -ms-animation: none;
 animation: none;
 color: transparent;
     opacity: 100;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;

}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 color: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
 animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
 animation-delay: 14s;
}
.sp-globe {
 position: absolute;
 width: 282px;
 height: 273px;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
 background: transparent url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
 opacity: 0.3;
 -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 -moz-transform: scale(5);
 -o-transform: scale(5);
 -ms-transform: scale(5);
 transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #3f1616;
 font-size: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
 background: #85373b;
 color: #fff;
}
/**/
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%,75%{
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{

  opacity: 0;
   -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.5;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
     -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
   -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%,75%{
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
     -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
-ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/
@keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%,75%{
  opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;

  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.5;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;

  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;

  transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        zoom: 1;

  transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
-ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);

  transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInRotate{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);

  transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
 -ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);

  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}

</style>
<div id="agentie-de-publicitate-full-service" class="container1">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sp-container">
        <div class="sp-content">
            <div class="sp-globe"></div>
             <h2 class="frame-1">Afacerea ta are nevoie de un progres?</h2>

             <h2 class="frame-2">Vrei sa iți depășești concureța și nu știi cum? </h2>

             <h2 class="frame-3">Hai să facem afacerea ta cunoscută !</h2>

             <h2 class="frame-4">Acum !</h2>

             <h2 class="frame-5"><span>ALL INCLUDED</span> <span>AGENȚIE DE PUBLICITATE </span> <span>FULL SERVICE</span></h2>
 <a class="sp-circle-link" href="#agentie-de-publicitate-full-service">Apasă !</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-ms-filter` rule in `@-*-keyframes` has wrong quotation marks. It's `”` and it's not `"` nor `'`. Try changing it to normal.

(Most likely you have copy-pasted text from somewhere else and sometimes it contains wrong character for quotes).

Comment: Hi Justinas, thanks for answearing my question, I change the quotation marks but I have same problem.   https://jsfiddle.net/m6honjt5/2/

Comment: Hi Pistol, your jsfiddle mashup works find with IE11. Media queries (@Media) do not work in IE9 and lower or in the same IE Emulation modes.

Comment: Thank you for answearing my question, it is a way to not display this animation for IE9 or all IE version? A java code or something ?

Comment: @PistolAlexandru Check IE conditional comments.

Comment: Thank you both for helping me, I hate IE honestly. Have a nice day !